# Python 3 list with range and other individual numbers

Tags: list, python-3.x, append, range

I need to make a list of numbers.  These numbers represent binary masks.  The first 100 or so masks are all included in this range.  In the next group of masks only certain masks are included.  I need a list similar to the following.

```
[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,30,34,48,53,62]
```

Can I do something like `[range(1,10),30,34,48,53,62]`

or do I need to create my list using range(1,10) and then append the next list to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 actually allow you to build a list literal prepending an `*` to any iterable objects - which are in turn expanded in place:

```
>>> [1,2, *range(10), *range(2)]
[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
```

If you need this n older Pythons, or if you'd prefer to keep readability for people not too proeficient in Python who might have to walk through your code, an option is just to concatenate your different list fragments using  the  `+` operator:

```
a = list(range(1,10)) + [ 30,34,48,53,62]
```

Comment: Let me revise my question a little since I didn't know this would make a difference, but it seems to.  I am using this to populate a value in a dictionary.  {"onState":[*range(1,65),45,52,54]
it won't let me use a "*" in anything other than an assignment statement.

Comment: you certainly can do `{ "onState":[*range(1,65), 42, 52, 54]}`  the syntax allowed for list literals won't change regardless of the place were you are placing the literals.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to use the list(range(1,10)+[47,34,57] 
solution